# Teensy 3.1/3.2 - region `FLASH' overflowed by 86948 bytes while program is 40kb

Tags: c++, platformio, teensy

I’m using Teensy 3.2 and cannot build my teensy code due to two warnings resulting in an error 1 return.

Warning 1 - *.pio/build/teensy31/firmware.elf section .text' will not fit in region FLASH’*

Warning 2 - *region `FLASH’ overflowed by 86948 bytes*

Error - *collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

From what I read it basically means that the file is too large but my src folder is 40129 bytes and Teensy 3.2 flash size is 262144 bytes as it is written in the platforms/teensy/boards/teensy31.json file.
**Even the build begins with >**
*Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option*
*CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/teensy/teensy31.html*
*PLATFORM: Teensy (4.16.0) > Teensy 3.1 / 3.2*
*HARDWARE: MK20DX256 72MHz, 64KB RAM, 256KB Flash*
*DEBUG: Current (jlink) External (jlink)*
*PACKAGES:*
*- framework-arduinoteensy @ 1.156.0 (1.56)*
*- toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi @ 1.50401.190816 (5.4.1)*

The src folder is a cpp file (with setup and loop functions) + 4 header files surrounding it with functions used in the cpp file. Also, the **2 warnings in the .h files are unrelated** to the issue.
[Tree for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSiEY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I read it basically means that the file is too large but my
> src folder is 40129 bytes and Teensy 3.2 flash size is 262144

The size of your src folder has not much to do with the size of the generated program. If you are interested in where all that memory goes to you can use an ELF viewer.

For example, here you find an online viewer: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/onlineelfviewer/onlineelfviewer.html.
Upload your elf file and scroll down to the symbol table section to find out what eats up that huge amount of memory.

Comment: Got it, I included "iostream" for some reason which caused my memory size to skyrocket. Thanks for the help!